# What does CreateItem do in VBA for outlook emails?

Tags: vba, outlook

Why do we use `CreateItem` to create a `MailItem` in VBA as opposed to the New keyword? More generally, what’s the difference between the two methods? I noticed that to create an instance of the app we do:

```
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
```

However for the MailItem we do:

```
Set OutlookEmail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

Tried the above method and it worked but am wondering why it works like that.

Comment: The MailItem needs to be created from the Application object because it requires that association. The application object is created from scratch, so it does not need a parent item in order to be created.

Answer (score 1):

They are entirely different lines of code. In the first case a new Outlook `Application` instance is created:

```
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
```

That is actually all what you could do with the `New` operator and Outlook object model. Everything else is retrieved from using methods and properties available in the Outlook object model. For example, there are several ways of creating a new `MailItem` instance:

```
Set OutlookEmail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

And

```
Set OutlookEmail = folder.Items.Add(olMailItem)
```

The difference is where the item will be saved when calling `Save()`.

You can read more about possible ways of creating Outlook items in the article which I wrote for the technical blog, see [How to create and show a new Outlook mail item programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/26/outlook-create-show-message-programmatically/).